# SVG : rotate whole texte

Tags: css, angularjs, svg

I want to rotate one list of words with an angle.
But only the characters are tilted : [image: Only characters are tilted]

My code is here :

```
<svg width="2000" height="130">
      <g *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
        <g>
          <text [attr.x]="fruit.x" [attr.y]=50 dx=-10 dy=-7 rotate="-30 fruit.x 50">
            {{fruit.name}}
          </text>
        </g>
      </g>
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance for your help to rotate all the words

Comment: Please try to use something like `transform="rotate(-30,100,50)"` instead of `rotate`

Comment: I try this but unfortunately it doesn't work for me, thank you though enxaneta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've commented you need to use `transform="rotate(...` instead of `rotate`

```html
<svg width="2000" height="130">
      <g>
        <g>
          <text x="100" y=50 dx=-10 dy=-7 transform="rotate(-30 100 50)">
            fruit name 1
          </text>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g>
        <g>
          <text x="200" y=50 dx=-10 dy=-7 transform="rotate(-30 200 50)">
            fruit name 2
          </text>
        </g>
      </g>
</svg>
```

If this is not working for you please update your code with an working example.

Comment: I think that my problem comes from my variable inside the transform attribute : transform="rotate(-30 fruit.x 50)". I iterate over a list to generate the text elements